# Collection was of a fixed size

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

```
Private Sub XamMenuItem_DeleteClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim selectedRowCount As Integer = Grid.SelectionSettings.SelectedRows.Count
        If (Grid.Rows.Count >= selectedRowCount) Then
            While Grid.SelectionSettings.SelectedRows.Count > 0
                Dim index As Integer = Grid.SelectionSettings.SelectedRows(0).Index
                If index >= 0 Then
                    DeleteRow(index)
                End If
            End While
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRow(ByVal rowNumber As Integer)
        If Grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Grid.Rows(rowNumber).Delete() --->**NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.**
        End If
End Sub
```

Please help the above code throws me a "Collection was of a fixed size". Would appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using XtraGrid or at least something from DevExpress. [According to their forums](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/31058.aspx):

> Rows can be added/deleted in the XtraGrid using the AddNewRow and
>   DeleteRow methods only if the bound data source supports the
>   IBindingList interface and implements the corresponding methods of the
>   interface. You can refer to the GridIBindingList tutorial for an
>   example.

What datasource are you using? An array?